# PGFplot multiple histograms using CSV file

Tags: pgfplots, csv

I have tried to draw a comparative graph using histogram and taking data from different CSV source files. I can draw the two histograms but the resulting graph is not what I want: I don't want the two histograms to be merged.
My tex file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepgfplotslibrary{units}

 \sisetup{
  round-mode          = places,
  round-precision     = 2,
  }

  \begin{document}

  \begin{figure}[h!]
  \begin{center}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
      width=15cm, height=8cm,     
      grid=major, 
      grid style={dashed,gray!30}, 
      xlabel=String length, 
      ylabel=Performance ops/ms,
      legend style={at={(0.5,-0.2)},anchor=north},
      xmode=log,
      log ticks with fixed point,
      xtick=data,  
              ]
    \addplot[ybar,fill] table[x="length",y="Score", col sep=comma} {jmh-result1.csv}; 
    \addplot[green,ybar,fill] table[x="length",y="Score", col sep=comma] {jmh-result2.csv};
     \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Performance Comparison Histogram}
 \end{center}
 \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Here is the output I get:
[image]

What I want is aligned histograms like this example in `pgfplot` gallery :

[image]

The following code is used to do that:

```
symbolic x coords={tool8,tool9,tool10},
\addplot coordinates {(tool8,7) (tool9,9) (tool10,4)}; 
\addplot coordinates {(tool8,4) (tool9,4) (tool10,4)}; 
\addplot coordinates {(tool8,1) (tool9,1) (tool10,1)};
```

I am not sure if there is a way to do the same without explicitly defining the value of the coordinates in the tex file.

Note: The value of the length in both files is the same {1,2,4,...,64}, only the score changes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add the `ybar` option to the `axis` options, instead of to each plot individually. Note that the author of `pgfplots` recommends not to use the `newest` `compat` option, and also I think that loading the `pgfplotslibrary` `units` is redundant if you also load `siunitx`. Finally, `pgfplots` already loads `tikz` so no need for duplication there either :-)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}

 \sisetup{
  round-mode          = places,
  round-precision     = 2,
  }

  \begin{document}

  \begin{figure}[h!]
  \begin{center}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
      width=15cm, height=8cm,
      grid=major,
      grid style={dashed,gray!30},
      xlabel=String length,
      ylabel=Performance ops/ms,
      legend style={at={(0.5,-0.2)},anchor=north},
      xmode=log,
      log ticks with fixed point,
      xtick=data,
      ybar, %added here
              ]
    \addplot[fill] table[x="length",y="Score", col sep=comma] {jmh-result1.csv};
    \addplot[green,fill] table[x="length",y="Score", col sep=comma] {jmh-result2.csv};
     \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Performance Comparison Histogram}
 \end{center}
 \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]