# Plot multiple histograms from csv file using pgfplot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, csv

I have the following `data.csv` file:

```
subject,f1,f2,f3
F11,0.019,0.04165,0.00016547
F14,0.03034,0.02161,0.000267
M22,0.05128,0.0648,0.000327
M22_1,0.052,0.0328,0.000206
M23,0.0364,0.06355,0.000379
F37,0.02856,0.081253,0.00019
```

and I would like to plot three histograms (f1,f2,f3) for each subject.
I am currently trying with this code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{axis}[width=10cm, height=5cm,legend pos=outer north east,xlabel=ages,ylabel=values,ticks with fixed point,xtick=data,ybar,ymin=0,ymax=0.1,ytick={0,0.04,0.08}]
 \addplot [color=blue,fill] table [x expr=\coordindex, y={f1}, col sep=comma] {data.csv};
  \addplot [color=green,fill] table [x expr=\coordindex, y={f2}, col sep=comma] {data.csv};
  \addplot [color=red,fill] table [x expr=\coordindex, y={f3}, col sep=comma] {data.csv};
  \legend{f1,f2,f3}
 \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

But subject ids (F11,...,F37) on the x axis do not appear. Moreover, I would like to move the legend on the bottom.

I found a similar question [PGFplot multiple histograms using CSV file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/245257/pgfplot-multiple-histograms-using-csv-file), but I did not understand how to solve my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the tick labels from the table, use `xticklabels from table={\mydata}{subject}`, where `\mydata` is the table, and `subject` is the name of the column. To place the legend below, I used `legend to name={label}`, which lets you place the legend where you like with `\ref{label}`. I used a node placed relative to the axis. Note also that I added `$ ... $` around the subscripted number in the `subject` column.

`pgfplotstableread` can take the raw values as input (as in my original answer), or the filename of a text file. To remove the scientific notation from the yticklabels, see e.g. [pgfplot: accuracy of tick labels](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35909/pgfplot-accuracy-of-tick-labels) or [Remove the scientific notation which is unreasonable](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119887/remove-the-scientific-notation-which-is-unreasonable).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
% the filecontents package and environment allows you to create a new file
% this is just to make the example self contained, I don't suppose you'll use it yourself
\begin{filecontents*}{data.dat}
subject,f1,f2,f3
F11,0.019,0.04165,0.00016547
F14,0.03034,0.02161,0.000267
M22,0.05128,0.0648,0.000327
M22$_1$,0.052,0.0328,0.000206
M23,0.0364,0.06355,0.000379
F37,0.02856,0.081253,0.00019
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{pgfplots,pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{data.dat}\mydata

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=10cm, height=5cm,
  legend style={legend columns=-1},
  legend to name={thelegend},
  name={theaxis},
  xlabel=ages,
  ylabel=values,
  xtick=data,
  xticklabels from table={\mydata}{subject},
  ybar,
  ymin=0,ymax=0.1,
  ytick={0,0.04,0.08},
  yticklabel style={
        /pgf/number format/fixed,
        /pgf/number format/precision=2
}]
\addplot [color=blue,fill] table [x expr=\coordindex, y={f1}] \mydata;
\addplot [color=green,fill] table [x expr=\coordindex, y={f2}] \mydata;
\addplot [color=red,fill] table [x expr=\coordindex, y={f3}] \mydata;
\legend{f1,f2,f3}
\end{axis}
\node [below] at (theaxis.below south) {\ref{thelegend}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, that's great. Is there any way to use the file csv instead of writing down all the values? Moreover, I would prefer to have on the y axis numbers in the decimal format (0.04 and 0.08) instead of the exponential format because of space.

Comment: @werty Of course, I just couldn't be bothered to make a new file -- just add the filename to `pgfplotstableread` instead of all the values. For the ticklabels, see e.g. [Remove the scientific notation which is unreasonable](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/119887) I'll update my answer in a bit.

Comment: Thank you. Just to more questions: 1) Is it possible to force the 0 in the yaxis to be exactly $0$ instead of $0.00$ in double precision as other numbers on the y axis? 2) Is it possible to draw the "trend" for each histogram as in this picture http://i.stack.imgur.com/mZKaD.png ?

Comment: @werty 1) I don't see that behaviour, I get just `0` as you see in the screenshot. 2) Probably, but I don't know how. `\addplot [sharp plot] table [x expr=\coordindex, y={f1}] \mydata;` doesn't really work. I suggest you ask a new question about that problem.